# Prove that $3^{101}$ divides $2^{3^{100}}+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that $3^{101}$ divides $2^{3^{100}}+1$? I wanted to use the Little Fermat's Theorem, but there are two problems. We have $1$ instead of $-1$, and most important, we do not know that $3^{101-1}$ is prime.

Comment: $3^{100}$ is not prime, so we do know that $3^{101-1}$ is not prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^m+1 = \frac{4^m-1}{2^m-1}$. By [LTE](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/), $\nu_3(4^m-1)=1+\nu_3(m)$. If $m$ is odd then $3\nmid (2^m-1)$ and $\nu_3(2^m+1)=\nu_3(m)+1$. In particular $3^{101}\parallel \left(2^{3^{100}}+1\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Use induction to prove that $3^{n+1}$ divides $2^{3^n}+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Eulers theorem and $\phi(3^{101})=2\cdot 3^{100}$ , we have $2^{2\cdot 3^{100}}\equiv 1\mod 3^{101}$ , hence for $N:=2^{3^{100}}$ , we have $N^2\equiv 1\mod 3^{101}$ , hence $3^{101}|(N-1)(N+1)$

Since $N-1$ is not divisible by $3$, we have $\gcd(3^{101},N-1)=1$ and therefore $3^{101}|N+1$

Comment: A [very slight] variant to the 2nd part of the argument here is: $U = ({\mathbb Z}/3^{101} {\mathbb Z})^*$ is cyclic of even order, so $N^2=1$ has exactly $2$ solutions (with $N\in U$). Since $N\equiv -1 \pmod 3$, $N =-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$2^{2\cdot{3^{100}}}\equiv1(mod\ 3^{101})$

$(2^{3^{100}}+1)(2^{3^{100}}-1)\equiv0(mod\ 3^{101})$

The order of $2 (mod 3)$ is $2$ and $3^{100}$ is odd.

So, $3$ not dividing $2^{3^{100}}-1$

Answer (score 0):

Since $2^{\text{odd}}-1$ is not divisible by $3$ you could multiply by $2^{3^{100}}-1$ without affecting divisibility by $3$ to solve the first problem.

For the second you can use Euler's extension of Little Fermat and note that $\varphi(3^{101})=\left(1-\cfrac 13\right)\cdot 3^{101}$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $3^2|(2^{3^1}+1) = 9$ and $3^3|(2^{3^2})+1 = 513$. So this doesn't seem to be a specific case for $101$ but a general result. Let's try to prove $3^{n+1}|(2^{3^n}+1)$ for all $n$.

For $n=1$, it is done above. Then suppose $n \ge 2$ and for all $n$, argument holds. Then for $n+1$, we have 
$$2^{3^{n+1}}+1 = (2^{3^n})^3+1 = \big[(2^{3^n}+1)-1\big]^3+1 = a^3-3a^2+3a$$
by Binomial Theorem, where $a = 2^{3^n}+1$. Now, by inductive assumption $3^{n+1}|a \implies 3^{n+2}|3a$ and also $3^{n+2}|a^3$ (This is because we have $a = k\cdot3^{n+1} \implies a^3 = k^3\cdot3^{3n+3}= k^3\cdot3^{n+2}\cdot3^{2n+1}$). Therefore, $3^{n+2}|(a^3-3a+3a) = 2^{3^{n+1}}+1$. Then by induction, argument holds for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

We prove that $3^{n+1}|2^{3^n}+1$ using induction. This is obviously true for $n=0$ since $3|2+1$. Now suppose that $$3^{n+1}|2^{3^n}+1$$
this means $2^{3^n}+1=3^{n+1}q$ for some $q$. Then we're gonna show that

$$3^{n+2}|2^{3^{n+1}}+1$$

It's clear by our assumption that $3|2^{3^n}+1$ therefore $2^{3^n}=3k-1$ for some k. Also
$$\large 2^{3^{n+1}}+1=(2^{3^n})^3+1=(2^{3^n}+1)[(2^{3^n})^2-2^{3^n}+1]=3^{n+1}[(3k-1)^2-(3k-1)+1]q=3^{n+1}[9k^2-9k+3]q=3^{n+2}[3k^2-3k+1]q=3^{n+2}q^{'}$$
which implies $$3^{n+2}|2^{3^{n+1}}+1$$

and our proof is complete.